# pymongo unordered vs ordered bulk write speed

Tags: python, mongodb

**Context**:

I am trying to insert 6 millions of records to mongoDB using pymongo. I am using `bulk_write` method and I read around that using `unordered` version will be faster than using `ordered` version since `unordered` version will have parallel operations.

**Problem**:

The `unordered` version does not give any speed increase.

Anybody knows why?

Here is my pseudocode:

```
# document_to_add_list
import pymongo
from pymongo import UpdateOne, MongoClient
mongo_uri = 'mongodb+srv://name:password@some-shard.mongodb.net/admin'
mongo_client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
collection = mongo_client['database']['collection']

operations = []
for doc in document_list[0:]:
    key = dict((k, doc[k]) for k in ('key1', 'key2'))
    updated = {'$setOnInsert': doc}
    op = UpdateOne(key, updated, upsert=True)
    operations.append(op)

try:
    upsert_results = collection.bulk_write(operations, ordered=False)
except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(len(bwe.details['writeErrors']))

# I got about 0.01s per records insertion or about 100records/sec for both ordered and unordered
```

BTW if anybody wonders whether my collection is indexed, the answer is yes, it is indexed for those 2 keys I used ie. `key1` & `key2`

Each document looks something like this:

```
{
    created: datetime,
    updated: datetime,
    events: [{
        event_key1: event_value1,
        event_key2: event_value2,
        event_key3: event_value3,
        event_key4: event_value4,
        event_key5: event_value5,
    }],
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
    key4: value4,
    key5: value5,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is your thing, the following approach should be much faster. For the logic to work it relies on you have a **unique** index on key1, key2, and using an **unordered** `bulk_write()` to ignore any duplicate inserts.

```
db.mycollection.create_index([('key1', pymongo.ASCENDING),
                              ('key2', pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)

operations = []

for doc in document_list[0:]:
    key = dict((k, doc[k]) for k in ('key1', 'key2'))
    op = InsertOne(doc)
    operations.append(op)

try:
    upsert_results = db.mycollection.bulk_write(operations, ordered=False)
except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(len(bwe.details['writeErrors']))
```

To answer the original question, ordered vs unordered performance will only differ significantly if you have certain sharding or write concern configurations.

Comment: My collection is already indexed uniquely with those 2 keys. And I already tried using InsertOne instead of UpdateOne. No improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about it, if your `document_list` has 6m items, then you create another 6m in `updated`, you've likely topped out your memory and pretty much guaranteed everything will run slow.

Try chopping your update into smaller chunks and, combined with my previous answer, seeing if this improves things.

Comment: Hi @BellyBuster sorry it was not very clear in my example above but I do it in batches of 100K to 1M. I didn't do it 6m at once. But even so, it takes a lot of time to do it. At the moment, I tried to put the script in an instance closer to AWS instance where my mongodb lives.

Comment: Running the script in an instance in the same region where the database lives works wonder. I got 100x gain.

Comment: Glad it's sorted. I was getting 10k/second running locally so it had to be something like that.

Comment: That's really fast but I think it really depends on the document size too. I've seen people hitting 80K/sec but probably that's because of the sharding configuration too.